# Why does TileService wait several seconds to start an Activity?

Tags: android, android-service, android-app-quick-setting

I'm using a `TileService` as a shortcut to open my app's `Activity`. It does only that, and has no state.

It looks like this:

```
class QuickAccessTileService : TileService() {

    override fun onClick() {
        super.onClick()

        val intent = Intent(this, SlideOverActivity::class.java)
            .addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

        startActivityAndCollapse(intent)
    }
}
```

and it's declared in `AndroidManifest` as:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".service.QuickAccessTileService"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:label="@string/tile_label"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

As it stands, this works. However, when my application is stopped, the next time I try to open it *via* the quick settings panel, it takes **several seconds** to start the activity.

Here's what I know:

The Activity in itself isn't slow to start. Trying to open it *via* the launcher instead makes it quite clear.

The `Service` seems to be what's taking a while to start before `onClick` is even executed. It makes sense; the `Service` is probably not kept running in the background doing nothing while the app isn't running. However, this means that when the system detects a click on my `Tile`, **the `Service` has to be recreated first**, which takes way too long.

I'm not sure where to go from here — if my guesses are even right.

EDIT: As an important addition, I can reproduce this on a OnePlus 7 Pro running on Android Pie. This might be a OnePlus-specific issue as I cannot reproduce it on an emulator.

Comment: If you have not done so already, override `onCreate()` and `onBind()` in `QuickAccessTileService`, chaining to the superclass and logging the times they were called. Also log the time that `onClick()` was called. That will hopefully give you some clue as to what step of the process is the slow one: slow to create the service, slow to bind after creation, slow to call `onClick()` after binding, or slow to respond to your `startActivityAndCollapse()` by actually showing the activity.

Comment: `onCreate`, `onBind` and `onClick` are called only a few milliseconds from each other. Most of the waiting happens before `onCreate` is even called, which is just puzzling to me.

Comment: Agreed. Is this reproducible across multiple devices and OS versions?

Comment: Currently, I can reproduce this on a OnePlus 7 Pro API 27. I could have sworn this also happened on the emulator a few weeks ago; either I'm remembering it wrong or I fixed it by accident, because I cannot for the life of me reproduce it there on any Android version. So this might be a OnePlus issue after all. :/

Comment: @CommonsWare, I can reproduce this on a Huawei API 26, Not only onClick, onStartListening is delayed, or even not executed at all.

Comment: @zhongshu: My best guess is that this is a manufacturer-specific issue, where they messed with the way the notification shade works in a way that interferes with third-party tiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
class TileSettingClass : TileService() {

    override fun onClick() {

        super.onClick()

        val tile = qsTile
        if (tile.state == Tile.STATE_INACTIVE) {
            tile.state = Tile.STATE_ACTIVE
            val intent = Intent(this.applicationContext, YourActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent.action = "yourAction"
            applicationContext.startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            tile.state = Tile.STATE_INACTIVE
        }
        tile.updateTile()
    }
}
```

**Manifests**

```
<service
    android:name=".main.service.TileSettingClass"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tile_setting"
    android:label="@string/milliy"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```